# Angular 2 - Get all @input() in directives or component

Tags: angular, decorator, angular2-directives, angular2-decorators

Is there a way to get all component or directive property with `@Input` decorators in angular 2?

Comment: What do u mean by components or directive property?

Comment: all property of a class that declared with @Inputs() decorator.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to get all inputs value you can go with [ngOnChanges](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/OnChanges-class.html) hook.

```
class MyComponent implements OnChanges {
  @Input() myProp: any;
  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    console.log('ngOnChanges - myProp = ' + changes['myProp'].currentValue);
  }
}
```